# Mix Test - Test patterns did not match any file

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I wrote a few tests for my Elixir project and put them in the `test/` directory. Now that I run `mix test`, I get:

```
$ mix test
Test patterns did not match any file:
```

That's it, there's nothing after that. **Do I have to manually set the path for my tests?** A quick Google search did not reveal anything.

---

*This is what all of my tests look like:*

```
# project_dir/test/my_app/some_module.exs

defmodule MyApp.SomeModule.Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest MyApp.SomeModule

  test "method 1" do
    assert MyApp.SomeModule.method_1_works?
  end

  test "method 2" do
    assert MyApp.SomeModule.method_2_works?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All tests are supposed to end with `_test.exs`**. Renaming my tests from `some_module.exs` to `some_module_test.exs` fixed it, and now it works.

From `$ mix help test`:

> This task starts the current application, loads up
>   `test/test_helper.exs` and then requires all files matching the
>   `test/**/_test.exs` pattern in parallel.

---

*I'd still like to know if it's possible to manually configure test paths (even if the word 'test' doesn't come at the end).*

Comment: Yes, it is possible - run `mix help test` and see block Configuration. `:test_paths` - list of paths containing test files, defaults to
    `["test"]`. It is expected all test paths to contain a `test_helper.exs` file. `:test_pattern` - a pattern to load test files, defaults to `*_test.exs`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to change the test path rather than using the default? Running `mix new` should give you a good scaffold. Unless there's a compelling reason why you need to have your files not end in *_test.exs, I think it's better to stay with the default. Keeping it idiomatic and all that